# SQL set 01.01 as start of the financial year

Tags: mysql, sql, report

I have a `2 joins` for my `sql` `report` about carhiring days for each attendee in the `current` `year`. And we get the data in `one` `column` *carhire*, so I have to combine the results.
First join is `uscarhiring` second `europecarhiring`. Right now I can show the results for every user, but only all results for all years, `not` from the `current year` (starting `01.01`). Here is how I combine the `two joins`:

```
'CASE WHEN ISNULL(uscarhire.uscarhire) THEN
                            CASE WHEN ISNULL(europe.europecarhiring) THEN
                              0
                            ELSE
                              europe.europecarhiring
                            END
                          ELSE
                            CASE WHEN ISNULL(europe.europecarhiring) THEN
                              uscarhire.uscarhire
                            ELSE
                              uscarhire.uscarhire + europe.europecarhiring
                            END
                          END',
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Where is your entire query? this is just one column select

Comment: In the two joins are the two queries from the two tables `europecarhiring` and `uscarhire`. They both bring results in days. (sorry,I am a novice in sql)